"Drawing the target around the arrow"
The infamous Texas sharpshooter fires randomly at a barn door and then paints the targets around the bullet holes, creating the false impression of being an excellent marksman. The sharpshooter symbolizes the dangers of post-hoc theorizing, that is, of finding your hypothesis in the data. The Texas sharpshooter is commonly introduced without a reference to its progenitor. Who mentioned it first?
Cicero comes close:
"(…) for who, if he shoots at a mark all day long, will not occasionally hit it? We sleep every night and there is scarcely ever a night when we do not dream; then do we wonder that our dreams come true sometimes? Nothing is so uncertain as a cast of dice and yet there is no one who plays often who does not sometimes make a Venus-throw and occasionally twice or thrice in succession. Then are we, like fools, to prefer to say that it happened by the direction of Venus rather than by chance?" (Cicero, 44BC, De divinatione II, 59)
But this is not quite the same, since in Cicero's case the deception is achieved with a lot of effort (shooting arrows all day long), whereas painting around the arrow is much more efficient.
Recently I was attended to an old Hebrew text that featured this example, but it seems such a compelling analogy that it must have been known in antiquity as well. Would anyvody happen to know whether this example is mentioned in any Latin text?
Cheers,
EJ
PS Some of the above fragments are taken from https://www.bayesianspectacles.org/origin-of-the-texas-sharpshooter/

Out of curiosity What old Hebrew text contains this idea?

A blog post is at https://www.bayesianspectacles.org/origin-of-the-texas-sharpshooter-ii-the-dubner-maggid/. The link to the relevant Hebrew text is https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29117&st=&pgnum=88&hilite=
